# $\text{ZFGC}^{\text{−f}}+\text{BAFA}+\exists\kappa(κ \text{ is Reinhardt})$ and its implication

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

A. S. Daghighi, M. Golshani, J. D. Hamkins, and E. Jeřábek proved in "The foundation axiom and elementary self-embeddings of the universe" that, working in ZFGC$^{\text{−f}}$+BAFA, there are nontrivial automorphisms and elementary embeddings of the universe $V$ into itself.

Accordingly, Kunen inconsistency is circumscribed for this class of ill-founded theories.

Does it follow that $\text{ZFGC}^{\text{−f}}+\text{BAFA}+\exists\kappa(κ \text{ is Reinhardt})$ is a non inconsistent extension of $\text{ZFGC}^{\text{−f}}+\text{BAFA}$?

If so, is it known which of the large cardinal properties would $\text{ZFGC}^{\text{−f}}+\text{BAFA}+\exists\kappa(κ \text{ is Reinhardt})$ imply?

Comment: Let me stress that as noted at the end of Section 4, what we write about BAFA is mostly a survey of previously known results. I don’t recall whether it is already given in Boffa’s paper, but the existence of nontrivial elementary embeddings is definitely proved and used in an essential way in the Ballard–Hrbáček paper.

Comment: Dear Dr Jeřábek, thanks for the note. I oversimplified because I wasn't sure of which results you've presented in your paper was previously known.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm glad to hear you're reading our paper, which can be found here: [The foundation axiom and elementary self-embeddings of the universe](http://jdh.hamkins.org/foundation-axiom-and-self-embeddings-of-the-universe/). Click through to the arxiv for a pdf — and I note that the title you mention is from an earlier draft of this article, so you may want to look at the updated version of the article.

In theorem 1 of the article, we prove in $\text{ZFC}^{-f}$ that any $\Sigma_1$-elementary embedding $j:V\to V$ must fix every well-founded set, and in particular, every ordinal. This is the residue of the Kunen inconsistency in this foundation-ness context. It follows, however, that although as you mention BAFA proves the existence of nontrivial elementary embeddings $j:V\to V$, we do not get nontriviality on the ordinals, and so there are no Reinhardt cardinals here to be found. The embeddings provided by BAFA have no critical points.

Further, since the consistency strength of BAFA is no greater than that of ZFC, it follows also that consistency-wise, one cannot provably get any large cardinals from such an embbedding in $\text{ZFC}^{-f}$.

Comment: Professor Hamkins, thanks for the answer: I'm truly honored. The last paragraph of your answer stresses that $\exists\kappa (\kappa \text{ is Reinhardt})$ cannot be a theorem of a $\text{ZFC}^{-\text{f}}+\text{BAFA}$ theory.

Now, $\exists\kappa (\kappa \text{ is Reinhardt})$ cannot even (consistently) be added to $\text{ZFC}^{-\text{f}}+\text{BAFA}$ as an axiom because the existence of a Reinhardt cardinal implies the existence of nontrivial elementary embeddings of the $V$ into itself, whilst it is a consequence of $\text{ZFC}^{-\text{f}}$ that any such embedding is trivial.

Comment: Edit of the previous comment: "...whilst it is a consequence of $\text{ZFC}^{−\text{f}}$ that any such embedding is trivial _on the well-founded part of the universe_".

In my previous comment I was checking whether I'm getting it right.

Comment: @JDH:  Is there any further weakening of $ZFC^{-f}$ that will keep will keep some $\Sigma_1$-elementary embedding j: $V$$\rightarrow$$V$ from fixing every well-founded set, and in particular, every ordinal so that one can get nontriviality on the ordinals?

Comment: If you drop AC, then it is not known whether there can be such an embedding nontrivial on the well-founded sets. This is the situation of Reinhardt cardinals in ZF without AC.

Comment: @JDH:  Are there any papers that have results regarding nontrivial elementary embeddings j:$V$$\rightarrow$$V$ in $ZF^{-f}$+$BAFA$?  Is it possible to prove an analogue to your Thm.1 in this system?  Is the consistency strength of $BAFA$ no greater than $ZF$ as well?

Comment: Our treatment of BAFA makes use of a Global Choice principle, which seems required to make the back-and-forth argument succeed. I am not aware of a treatment without any AC that gets elementary embeddings.

Comment: @JDH:  What is the minimal choice principle needed in order to construct elementary embeddings in $ZF^{-f} +$BAFA?

Comment: The only argument that I know uses the global choice principle, and this is stronger than mere AC.

Comment: @JDH:  So is one essentially 'stuck' with the Kunen inconsistency?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: @JDH: Well, if it is AC (or global choice) that gets one the Kunen inconsistency and one needs AC (or global choice) to get elementary embeddings (especially for nontrivial elementary embeddings j:$V$$\rightarrow$$V$), then one cannot  seemingly get around the Kunen inconsistency.

Comment: I basically agree, except that we don't know that choice is required in the BAFA case (or that it is required for the Kunen inconsistency).

Comment: (cont.) In fact, can one even define Reinhardt cardinals in 'choiceless' models of $ZF^{-f}$ (it is known that 'choiceless' models of $ZF$ 'exist' so it seems natural to hypothesize that 'choiceless' models of $ZF^{-f}$ 'exist, too).

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins:  Are you familiar with Athanassios Tzouvaras' paper "Cardinality without enumeration"?  I quote the abstract:  "we show that the notion of cardinality of a set is independent from that of wellordering, and that reasonable total notions of cardinality exist in every model of $ZF$ where the axiom of choice fails.  Such notions are either definable in a simple and natural way, or nondefinable, , produced by forcing.  Analogous cardinality notions exist in nonstandard models of arithmetic admitting nontrivial automorphisms.  Certain motivating phenomena from quantum

Comment: (cont.) mechanics are also discussed in the Appendix."  I'm wondering if Reinhardt cardinals in $ZF$ (and also $ZF^{-f}+BAFA$) might be cardinals of this type.