# Is there no anti-foundational theory exists Reinhardt and hold Global Choice?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

J. D. Hamkins proved in ["The foundation axiom and elementary self-embeddings of the universe"](http://jdh.hamkins.org/foundation-axiom-and-self-embeddings-of-the-universe/) that, working in $ZFGC^− +BAFA$, there are nontrivial automorphisms and elementary embeddings of the universe **V** into itself.

But, he say "so (BAFA) there are no Reinhardt cardinals here to be found. The embeddings provided by BAFA have no critical points." in this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/200544/143814). What does he mean for **"no critical points"**?

(1) Can we use Kunen's inconsistency theorem to proof $ZFGC^- + BAFA + Reinhardt \to 0=1$?

(2) Can Kunen inconsistency make sure there is no "useful" anti-foundational axiom in **[MK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory)-AF+Reinhardt** and **[TG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory)-AF+Reinhardt**?

Comment: He means no ordinals are moved.

Comment: This post is not written in good mathematical English: "to proof" and "no any" are always inappropriate, and "mean for" is inappropriate here. I can not understand question 2 at all. It might help to apply GoogleTranslate after writing the post in some other language, or to compare and combine computer-translated results with the English text proposed so far.

Comment: the title is not that clear?

Comment: @MattF. Sorry, I'm not Living in English country. I'm delete "any". "no critical points" just the motivation for my problem.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar, if the title question and question 2 are clear to you, you can edit the post, and the edits would likely be approved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, anti-foundation axioms have nothing to do with issues of large cardinal consistency strength.  You can take your universe of set theory with foundation and convert it into a universe with your favorite antifoundation axiom and no large cardinals will be created or destroyed.  This process is reversible:  large cardinals have nothing to do with anti-foundation axioms.